# Backtracking maze algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, backtracking, maze

I'm having some issues implementing backtracking for solving a maze, the issue I'm having is that if the player gets to a dead end, it doesn't go back to where it have another solution. In the case i developed just by coincidence at first it worked because of the order of the methods, but if i put that the player moves first east, it reaches a dead end and doesn't backtrack. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Laberinto {

    int posicionX = 0;
    int posicionY = 0;

    int largo = 6;
    int ancho = 6;

    int solX = 5;
    int solY = 4;

    boolean[][] cordenadas = new boolean[largo][ancho];

    int[] bloqueadasX = {1,2,3,4,5,5,0,2,3,4,5,0,2,3,4,5,3,0,1,5};
    int[] bloqueadasY = {0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,5,5};

    public ArrayList<Coordenada> recorridas = new ArrayList<Coordenada>();

    public Laberinto(int xo,int yo) {
        posicionX = xo;
        posicionY = yo;

        recorridas.add(new Coordenada(posicionX,posicionY));
    }

    public void recorrer() {

        if(posicionX==solX && posicionY == solY) {
            System.out.println("Solucion encontrada");
        }
        else {
            if(este(posicionX,posicionY)) recorrer();
            if(norte(posicionX,posicionY)) recorrer();
            if(sur(posicionX,posicionY)) recorrer();

            if(oeste(posicionX,posicionY)) recorrer();

            volver(new Coordenada(posicionX,posicionY));
        }
    }

    public void armarLaberinto() {

        for(int i=0;i<ancho;i++) {  
            for(int j=0;j<largo;j++) {
                    cordenadas[j][i] = estaBloqueada(j,i);  
            }       
        }

    }

    public boolean estaBloqueada(int x,int y) {

        for(int i=0;i<bloqueadasX.length;i++) {
            if(x==bloqueadasX[i] && y==bloqueadasY[i]) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean norte(int x,int y) {

            if(dentroTablero(x,y-1)) {

                if(!yaRecorrido(new Coordenada(x,y-1))) {

                    if(estaBloqueada(x,y-1)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    posicionY = posicionY-1;
                    recorridas.add(new Coordenada(x,y));

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            return false;

    }

    public boolean sur(int x,int y) {

        if(dentroTablero(x,y+1)) {

            if(!yaRecorrido(new Coordenada(x,y+1))) {

                if(estaBloqueada(x,y+1)) {
                    return false;
                }
                posicionY = posicionY+1;
                recorridas.add(new Coordenada(x,y));

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;

        }
     public boolean este(int x,int y) {

            if(dentroTablero(x+1,y)) {

                if(!yaRecorrido(new Coordenada(x+1,y))) {

                    if(estaBloqueada(x+1,y)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    posicionX = posicionX+1;
                    recorridas.add(new Coordenada(x,y));

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            return false;
    }

    public boolean oeste(int x,int y) {

            if(dentroTablero(x-1,y)) {

                if(!yaRecorrido(new Coordenada(x-1,y))) {

                    if(estaBloqueada(x-1,y)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    posicionX = posicionX-1;
                    recorridas.add(new Coordenada(x,y));

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            return false;
    }

    public boolean dentroTablero(int x, int y) {
        if((x >=0 && x<=ancho) && (y>=0 && y<=largo) ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean yaRecorrido(Coordenada a) {

        for(int i=0;i<recorridas.size();i++) {
            if(recorridas.get(i).getX() == a.getX() && recorridas.get(i).getY() == a.getY()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void volver(Coordenada a) {  
        recorridas.remove(a);
    }

    public void bloqueadas() {

            armarLaberinto();

            for(int i=0;i<ancho;i++) {  
                for(int j=0;j<largo;j++) {

                    if(!cordenadas[j][i]) {

                        if(j==solX && i==solY) {
                            System.out.print("M");

                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.print("◘");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

        }

    public void mostrarRecorrido() {

        armarLaberinto();

        for(int i=0;i<ancho;i++) {  
            for(int j=0;j<largo;j++) {

                if(!cordenadas[j][i]) {

                    if(j==solX && i==solY) {
                        System.out.print("M");

                    }
                    else {

                        if(yaRecorrido(new Coordenada(j,i))) {
                            System.out.print("•");
                        }
                        else {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print("◘");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Laberinto laberinto = new Laberinto(0,0);
        laberinto.armarLaberinto();
        laberinto.bloqueadas();
        laberinto.recorrer();
        laberinto.mostrarRecorrido();

        System.out.println(laberinto.posicionX);
        System.out.println(laberinto.posicionY);
    }

}
```

Comment: Still trying to read your code, non english code is half way to obfuscated to me.. But one critique, try to unify your 4 direction checks into 1 functions. A moral of mine, if I have to copy paste more than a line of my own code, I am probably doing something wrong..

Comment: Have you verified that you have a solution at all for your maze? Try adding print statements which show the current position and see where it gets stuck

Comment: And your direction checks should probably be if-else checks

Comment: Karthik T hey karthik thanks for the answer ! yes i know im sorry for the language, related to your moral, i do the same as you but in this case, if i only do one function for all the movements that would make me do a switch statement (which will take more processing time), i could do the movement directly on the function but then it would not be clear for reading !

Comment: Your own processing time is far more important than your machine's CPU processing time if you understand me :)

Comment: @Karthik T  yes i did, the maze has a solution and the algorithm finds it when the methods are call this way (north,south,east,west) but if you call them like this (east,north,south,west) then it gets to a dead end and doesnt backtrack :/

Comment: And there are atleast a couple of ways I can think of doing this without switch, which would indeed be kinda ugly

Comment: One way, best I can think of, is to have a 2D array holding the +1 and 0s as (X,Y) pairs, indexed by the direction, then you can use a Enum to get the delta, and pass that enum from your search function into your "CanWalkToPosition" method (dont name a method "north"!!)

Comment: @gabrielmellace I think the reason why the north,south,east,west work for you is because you can notice that, based on the maze configuration and on the default starting point you selected, there is no need for back-tracking. If you change the configuration then it is probable that you will face the same problem.

Comment: gabrielmellace The part of the code that is supposed to go back to the previous step and try again is not working right (which is what I implied in the answer I posted below, but my English is sometimes not good :) ). It is not going back to the previous position and attempting to find the way out again. Re-structuring the code to make it more simpler, as @KarthikT suggested, is a valuable suggestion to improve code readability and understandability. This could help you spot bugs easier.

Answer (score 0):

One possible bug is you have a global for your position. This would confuse your search a lot, once the first call fails to find the solution. Try to keep `posicionX,posicionY` as local to that function if possible.